# Flutter Calendar Map/List convert

Tags: flutter, dart

at first I want to show you my code, which i created and then I ask my question.
This here is a basic Map which contains no information.

```
Map<DateTime, List<Event>> selectedEvents;

List<Event> _getEventsfromDay(DateTime date) {
    return selectedEvents[date] ?? [];
 }
```

This here is my Code:

```
void main() {
    var jsonSource = """
  {
   "Events": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "event_name": "Cake tasting",
            "event_photo": "https://dispensaries.s3.amazonaws.com/event_photo/Southern_Cali_Kush_3.jpg",
            "vendor_name": {
                "id": 1,
                "vendor": "Tastey Cakes"
            },
            "refund_available": false,
            "website": "www.foodcakes.com",
            "share_count": 0,
            "check_in_count": 0,
            "street_address": "123 Fake Street",
            "city": "Brooklynn",
            "state": "NY",
            "zipcode": "12312",
            "event_tagline": "Taste my cakes",
            "details": "Cake tasting",
            "start_date": "2020-11-03",
            "start_time": "23:33:00",
            "end_time": "23:33:00",
            "attendees": []
        }
    ]
    }
  """;
    print(convertJsonToDateMap(jsonSource));
  }

  Map<DateTime, List> convertJsonToDateMap(String jsonSource) {
    var json = jsonDecode(jsonSource);
    var jsonEvents = json['Events'];
    Map<DateTime, List<String>> events = {};
    for(var event in jsonEvents){
      var date = parseDate(event['start_date']);
      events.putIfAbsent(date, () => <String>[]);
      events[date].add(event['event_name']);
    }
    return events;
  }

  DateTime parseDate(String date) {
    var parts = date.split('-').map(int.tryParse).toList();
    return DateTime(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
  }
```

How to write my code that the 2. code is working like the first, so that the json is stored as Map/List.
I am Flutter beginnen and dont know how to do this.

Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Model Like This :

```
import 'dart:convert';

EventModel eventModelFromJson(String str) => EventModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String eventModelToJson(EventModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class EventModel {
    EventModel({
        this.events,
    });

    List<Event> events;

    factory EventModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EventModel(
        events: List<Event>.from(json["Events"].map((x) => Event.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Events": List<dynamic>.from(events.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Event {
    Event({
        this.id,
        this.eventName,
        this.eventPhoto,
        this.vendorName,
        this.refundAvailable,
        this.website,
        this.shareCount,
        this.checkInCount,
        this.streetAddress,
        this.city,
        this.state,
        this.zipcode,
        this.eventTagline,
        this.details,
        this.startDate,
        this.startTime,
        this.endTime,
        this.attendees,
    });

    int id;
    String eventName;
    String eventPhoto;
    VendorName vendorName;
    bool refundAvailable;
    String website;
    int shareCount;
    int checkInCount;
    String streetAddress;
    String city;
    String state;
    String zipcode;
    String eventTagline;
    String details;
    DateTime startDate;
    String startTime;
    String endTime;
    List<dynamic> attendees;

    factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
        id: json["id"],
        eventName: json["event_name"],
        eventPhoto: json["event_photo"],
        vendorName: VendorName.fromJson(json["vendor_name"]),
        refundAvailable: json["refund_available"],
        website: json["website"],
        shareCount: json["share_count"],
        checkInCount: json["check_in_count"],
        streetAddress: json["street_address"],
        city: json["city"],
        state: json["state"],
        zipcode: json["zipcode"],
        eventTagline: json["event_tagline"],
        details: json["details"],
        startDate: DateTime.parse(json["start_date"]),
        startTime: json["start_time"],
        endTime: json["end_time"],
        attendees: List<dynamic>.from(json["attendees"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "event_name": eventName,
        "event_photo": eventPhoto,
        "vendor_name": vendorName.toJson(),
        "refund_available": refundAvailable,
        "website": website,
        "share_count": shareCount,
        "check_in_count": checkInCount,
        "street_address": streetAddress,
        "city": city,
        "state": state,
        "zipcode": zipcode,
        "event_tagline": eventTagline,
        "details": details,
        "start_date": "${startDate.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${startDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${startDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "start_time": startTime,
        "end_time": endTime,
        "attendees": List<dynamic>.from(attendees.map((x) => x)),
    };
}

class VendorName {
    VendorName({
        this.id,
        this.vendor,
    });

    int id;
    String vendor;

    factory VendorName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VendorName(
        id: json["id"],
        vendor: json["vendor"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "vendor": vendor,
    };
}
```

---

To parse this JSON data, do

final eventModel = eventModelFromJson(jsonString);

Then Check the Map